# Why Chrome Dev Tool shows a 200 status code instead of 304

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-chrome-devtools, cache-control

While I was testing a weird behaviour in cache handling with Chrome (I asked something about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016037/chrome-doesnt-send-if-none-match-header-in-https-but-sends-it-in-http)), I found something else: Chrome dev tool shows a 200 status code when the server returns a 304 response.

Here you can see what chrome dev tool says (200) and I included a wireshark capture that shows the server 304 response.

[image]

Here is the same usage with Firefox, which shows the 304 code :

[image]

More interesting is the timing difference between the two browsers :

[image]

Firefox doesn't shows delay for the reception part but Chrome says it took 3.91ms.

Do you have any idea on why Chrome doesn't shows the right status code?

If you want to test yourself, here is the server code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const compression = require('compression');
const pathUtils = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const http = require('http');
let app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(compression({}));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.set('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
    console.log(req.headers);
    next();
});

let server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(fs.readFileSync(pathUtils.join(__dirname, 'dummy.txt')));
});

server.listen(1234);
```

and the client :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let test = fetch('http://localhost:1234/api/test').then((res) => {
                console.log(res.status);
                return res.text();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quite the same here, only diffrence is the server does not receive the request at all from Chrome. While firefox send the request and the server replies with 304 and it s well shown in the console.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I suspect that Chrome is just showing the cached response (including the cached response code) since the resource was successfully validated. Even when something is served from the cache and there's no request at all I believe Chrome shows the cached 200 as the response code. Kind of confusing, but not entirely unreasonable.

Answer (score 8):

I think that's actually a chrome bug. A bug report has been opened here : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1269602

Comment: Chrome bug report seems moved to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1086809

Answer (score 0):

Set the max-age. For example:

```
max-age=2592000,no-cache
```