# Chrome etag always show 200 ok but curl get the 304 not modified

Tags: http, etag

[image]

[image]

There are two pics, the first is send request in the brower, etag value always same and http status always 200 ok, base on the http etag stretegy, I would get the 304 not modified in this request. Then what make me doubt is when I copy the request as curl run in the bash, it worked, server return right 304 not modified.

My server side is Spring Boot, relate code is

```kotlin
  @Bean
  fun shallowEtagHeaderFilter(): ShallowEtagHeaderFilter? {
    return ShallowEtagHeaderFilter()
  }
```

Front side is react with axios, relate code is:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const request = axios.create({ 
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8082',
  timeout: 10000,
  withCredentials: true
})

export default request
```

I waiting for you response online, thanks for yous reading.

Answer (score 0):

Click View source button in the Response Headers part, maybe you will see HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified.

I don't know why Chrome shows status code 200 in General part.

A similar question: [Why Chrome Dev Tool shows a 200 status code instead of 304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017167/why-chrome-dev-tool-shows-a-200-status-code-instead-of-304)

[image]

And I tried my code in Firefox, the status code is 304.